# Averageifs with OR criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to run an AVERAGEIFS function across a date variable AND either criteria 1 OR criteria 2 out of a second range. Concept is below. I've found SUMPRODUCT or array formulas to solve the OR problem, but I'm not sure how to combine the date to those solutions. Thanks!

=+IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(AVERAGE RANGE,CRITERIA RANGE,(Criteria 1 OR Criteria 2),DATE RANGE,DATE)"")

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use SUMIFS and COUNTIFS:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(RANGE,CritRange,{Crit1,Crit2},DateRange,Date))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(RANGE,CritRange,{Crit1,Crit2},DateRange,Date)),"")
```